# Local Solvability of an Initial Value Problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem

$$
 f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       y'(x) = (1+y(x))f(y(x))\\
       y(0) =2 
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

If $f(y)$ is locally Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R}$, what can be said about the solvability of the problem? Is the solution unique?

My idea was to try to show that $g(y)=(1+y(x))f(y(x))$ satisfies a local Lipschitz property as well, however I couldn't come up with anything in the inequalities. I then wanted to apply an appropriate theorem to say that we have uniqueness and existence. What am I missing?

Comment: The product of two locally Lipschitz functions is locally Lipschitz. Idea: $|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)|\le |f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)|$.

Comment: Ah, and so we have, where $f$ and $g$ are both continuous in the neigborhood, and hence bounded by say, $M$ and $N$, then we have
$|f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)| \leq ML|x-y|+NL|x-y|$, where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant. Thanks.